# Create elements and addEventListener with Loop in Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile

Using Titanium Appcelerator I am trying to dynamically create elements and add event listeners to them using a loop. Here is my current code:

```
for(i=0;i<7;i++){

testLabels[i] = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    borderRadius: 35,
    text:'hello',
    textAlign:'center',
    width:70,
    height: 70,
    top: '13%',
    left:140,
    touchEnabled: true
});

    testLabels[i].addEventListener('click',function(e){
        //do something
    }
}
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
Can't find variable: testLabels.
```

Its interesting to me that the variable it can't find isn't "testLabels1", which to me means the loop isn't firing... any ideas?

Thanks!

Titanium doesn't like it when I place "var" in front of the label declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
var testLabels = [];
for(var i=0; i<7; i++ ) {

    testLabels[i] = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
        borderRadius: 35,
        text:'hello',
        textAlign:'center',
        width:70,
        height: 70,
        top: '13%',
        left:140,
        touchEnabled: true
    });

    (function(label) {
        label.addEventListener('click',function(e){
            //do something
        }
    }(testLabels[i]));

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!! Defining testLabels as an array was the answer. I can't believe I didn't see that.  The second part of your answer, to add event listeners, wasn't working for me. I ended up making it work like this:
 
theLabel = testLabels[i];
win2.add(theLabel);

theLabel.addEventListener('click',function(){
  
})